# Rewrite rule always redirect to wrong url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

**Hello All,**
I need to rewrite   http://mysite.com/user/profile/following?profile_name=MYNAME   to http://mysite.com/user/profile/MYNAME/following

I have written rule like this:

```
RewriteRule user/profile/(.*)/(.*) /user/profile/$2?profile_name=$1 [L,R=301]
```

when i put url like http://mysite.com/user/profile/MYNAME/following   in the browser it always redirect me to http://mysite.com/user/profile/following?profile_name=MYNAME

What did i miss?

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+user/profile/([^?]+)\?profile_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/profile/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^user/profile/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /user/profile/$2?profile_name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. But same result :(

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser, Is it  `http://mysite.com/user/profile/following?profile_name=MYNAME` ?

Comment: Also can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?

Comment: That will **internally** become `/user/profile/following?profile_name=MYNAME` (URL won't change in browser)